# How to change the NA value in barplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

when I try to plot `df` I find NA in the barplot. I can't understand why.
Here is `df`

```
dput(df)
structure(list(Cancer.type = c(" BLCA", " BLCA", " BLCA", "BRCA", 
"BRCA", "BRCA", "COAD", "COAD", "COAD", "ESCA", "ESCA", "ESCA", 
"GBM", "GBM", "GBM", "KIRC", "KIRC", "KIRC", "LIHC", "LIHC", 
"LIHC", "LUAD", "LUAD", "LUAD", "LUSC", "LUSC", "LUSC", "PRAD", 
"PRAD", "PRAD", "STAD", "STAD", "STAD", "THCA", "THCA", "THCA", 
"UCEC", "UCEC", "UCEC"), Number.of.genes = c(4L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 
6L, 2L, 1L, 10L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 8L, 2L, 4L, 10L, 2L, 8L, 6L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 5L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 9L, 8L, 3L, 
5L, 4L, 3L, 9L), Condition = c("Down ", "Up", "ns", "Down ", 
"Up", "ns", "Down ", "Up", "ns", "Down ", "Up", "ns", "Down ", 
"Up", "ns", "Down ", "Up", "ns", "Down ", "Up", "ns", "Down ", 
"Up", "ns", "Down ", "Up", "ns", "Down ", "Up", "ns", "Down ", 
"Up", "ns", "Down ", "Up", "ns", "Down ", "Up", "ns")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-39L))
```

Here is my script

```
ggplot(df,aes(fill = factor(Condition, levels = c('Down','Up','ns')),
               y = Number.of.genes, x =Cancer.type)) + 
 geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity")+theme_bw()+
   theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10, angle = 45, hjust = 1, colour = 'black'))+
   scale_fill_manual(values=c("seagreen2", "deepskyblue3",'goldenrod1'))+
   labs(fill = 'Condition', x = NULL)
```

[image]

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `Condition` column, the `Down` actually has a trailing space. So you can do 3 things:

1. remove the space from your data frame

`df$Condition <- gsub(' ', '', df$Condition)`

2. Add the space in `levels()`

`ggplot(df,aes(fill = factor(Condition, levels = c('Down ','Up','ns'))`

3. Remove the `levels` argument

`ggplot(df,aes(fill = factor(Condition)`